# cannot obtain linear solver MA27 from shared library using Ipopt

Tags: c++, ubuntu-18.04, ipopt

I want to use Ipopt as my solver and interface it with c++ using VScode on Ubuntu 18.04. I tried to install Ipopt following every step detailed on

https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node13.html

I can compile and everything is successful, but running

```
$ make test
```

as described by the Ipopt documentaion gives the following error:

> Exception of type: OPTION_INVALID in file "/home/peyman/CoinIpopt/Ipopt/src/Algorithm/IpAlgBuilder.cpp" at line 271:
>    Exception message: Selected linear solver MA27 not available.
>   Tried to obtain MA27 from shared library "libhsl.so", but the following error occured:
>   libhsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> EXIT: Invalid option encountered.
>
> An error occoured.
>    The error code is          -12

As a result of this error I cannot run

```
$ make install
```

to install Ipopt. I tried to redo all the steps but I get the same error over and over.

Comment: So, you are missing libhsl.so - go install it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, thanks for the comment. (I think!) I've already installed it, following the instructios of the Ipopt...

Comment: You've installed it - good. But it's obviously not being found. Have you run "ldconfig"? Is the library in a path searched by the dynamic linker? Where is the application looking for  the library - is there a custom RPATH? There are multiple things to check.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks. I'm fairly new to this area, could you please tell me how should I run idconfig ? Or how to check if the library is in a path searched by dynamic linker ? I appreciate it

Comment: i have same problem, have you solved it ?